# Erlang: lists:keyfind/3 vs dict:from_list/1 + dict:fetch/2 or dict:find/2

Tags: list, dictionary, erlang

If I have a list of Key Value tuples e.g. List = [{key1, value1}, {key2, value2}] is it better to use

lists:keyfind(Key, N, TupleList) e.g. lists:keyfind(key1, 1, List)

to find a given value or

dict:from_list(List)

to turn it into a dict and then lookup with dict:fetch/2 or dict:find/2 ?

Using a dict is more readable for me as it returns the value directly so I can use it inline, however I was wondering which was more efficient?

Thanks.

Comment: This may be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055391/time-complexity-of-erlang-dict

Comment: Scanning the list is most likely faster. Unless you are going to do it many times in which case converting it to a `dict` once is better. Why not use `dict` all the time instead of a list. An alternative if you want a list is to use `orddict` which keeps an **ordered** list and provides the same interface as `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have the option to use proplists:lookup(), part of the stdlib and pragmatically would be the most idiomatic way to express what you are doing. You would be manipulating the structure in its original form and your programmer peers would thank you for that. In terms of efficiency as you can see from the link below, the list is traversed until you find a match, any further appearances of the key are ignored.

[proplists.erl](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/lib/stdlib/src/proplists.erl#149)

The use of lists:keyfind() is another option less idiomatic probably so in my opinion looses points in favor of keeping consistency with the use of the structure as a proplist. The lists:keyfind() is a BIF which only tells us that is implemented in C not necessarily because of efficiency but very probable.

Finally the use of a list to dict in my opinion does not give you leverage on readability and you will be loosing consistency in terms of how the data structure was initially conceived, compared to the other two is probably the less efficient because you traverse the list to turn it to a dict and then you lookup the structure with the dict interface, so in my opinion you are loosing instead of gaining.

My two cents!

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't come across proplists. That does seem to be a clearer way of doing it without a dict. Your argument that traversing the list an additional time to create the dict is unnecessary is also convincing.

Comment: Regarding proplists vs. keyfind, please see my comments on the following blog entry: http://www.ostinelli.net/erlang-listskeyfind-or-proplistsget_value/